# Writing content of one file into another repetatively with perticular replacement

Tags: java, file, filestream

```
    BufferedReader template = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("<InputFile>"));
    PrintWriter itemList = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("<OutputFile>"));


    Iterator<String> iterator = allProduct.iterator();

    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        String l;
        while((l = template.readLine()) != null){
            if(l.contains("~")==false)
                itemList.print(l);                  
            else
                itemList.print(l.replace("~", iterator.next()));
        }

    }

    template.close();
    itemList.close();
```

but the programing is not terminating neither is it producing any error, it basically gets hanged.

Comment: Shouldn't you be advancing the outer loop? If the code never goes to the else branch in the inner loop you are never calling `iterator.next();`

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here. For all items in allProduct you are reading the file? Doesn't really make sense to me and sure is not the proper way to do this. Also if your if statement is never true you never call iterator.next().

Answer (score 0):

When you get to the end of your template file, `template.readLine()` will keep returning `null`, so you won't go in the inner `while` loop, therefore `iterator` won't be advanced.

Your code will be equivalent to this:

```
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    String l;
    // This bit commented out because template.readLine() always returns null
    //while((l = template.readLine()) != null){
    //    if(l.contains("~")==false)
    //        itemList.print(l);                  
    //    else
    //        itemList.print(l.replace("~", iterator.next()));
    //}

}
```

The solution is either to close and then re-open the file (not nice at all) or to separate the two: first read the template line by line into a list, then you only iterate across the list.

I'm only guessing but you probably don't want to call `iterator.next()` every time you encounter `~`, so I think you'll need something like this:

```
BufferedReader template = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("<InputFile>"));
    ArrayList<String> templateLines = new ArrayList<String>(); //this is where we store the lines from the template
    String l;
    while((l = template.readLine()) != null){ //read template lines
        templateLines.add( l );  //add to list
    }
    template.close();  //done

    PrintWriter itemList = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("<OutputFile>")); //now let's look at the output
    Iterator<String> iterator = allProduct.iterator();


    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        String product = iterator.next(); //take one product at a time
        for( String templateLine : templateLines ) { //for each line in the template
            if(templateLine.contains("~")==false) //replace ~ with the current product
                itemList.print(templateLine);                  
            else
                itemList.print(templateLine.replace("~", product));
        }

    }

    itemList.close();
```